I cannot assign migration to MySql database in C-Panel?
I have no problem when migrating to the MySql database in my locale, but I cannot migrate to the MySql database in C-Panel. After creating the database, I assign a user and set the connection string with his information. Where could I be making a mistake? I get an error like this;

The exception 'Plugin 'mysql_native_password' is not loaded' was
thrown while attempting to find 'DbContext' types. For the different
patterns supported at design time, see
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

appsettings.json folder
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=databaseName;Uid=userName;Pwd=password;"
  }
}

DbContext.cs folder

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Project.Context;

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    
    public DbSet<About> Abouts { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<SliderCaption> SilderCaptions { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Testimonial> Testimonials { get; set; } 
}

Program.cs Folder
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
});
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IAboutRepository, AboutRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IContactRepository, ContactRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPortfolioRepository, PortfolioRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISkillRepository, SkillRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISliderCaptionRepository, SliderCaptionRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITestimonialRepository, TestimonialRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
    var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    SeedData.Initialize(services, userManager, roleManager).Wait();
    services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();


After contacting the server side, they authorised it. After typing the IP address instead of localhost on the server, the operation was successful.
